# MongoDB - Find Difference Between Two Collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I have two collections:

### User

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    likes: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Products' }],
    dislikes: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Products' }],
})
```

### Product

```
var ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
})
```

I would like to return all of the products that is not in the User.likes or User.dislikes. Here is how I am currently doing it:

```
const user = await User.findById(req.user.id, 'likes dislikes');
let seenProducts = [];

user.likes.forEach(p => {
    seenProducts.push(new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(p));
})

user.dislikes.forEach(p=> {
    seenProducts.push(new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(p));
})

Product.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { _id: { $nin: seenProducts } },
    }
])
```

It works, but I would like to switch over to using the aggregration pipeline framework to do this if possible. It does not seem like it is easy to compare two collections... I have been trying this for a while with no luck. `$setUnion` and `$setDifference` look promising, but I can't find a way to set the union of the likes & dislikes of the user, and then the difference of that with all products.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.user.aggregate([{
  $lookup: {
    from: "product",
    pipeline: [{
      $match: {
        $or: [{
          likes: {
            $in: [ < ids or whatever > ]
          }
        }, {
          dislikes: {
            $in: [ < ids or whatever > ]
          }
        }]
      }
    }],
    as: "nameofthevariable"
  }
}])
```

Basically writing a lookup which works as a left outer join to fetch values from the products collection where either likes are  or dislikes are . $in allows you to put in multiple values as per requirement in this case.